# Find the value of the partial derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Find the value of

> $\dfrac{1}{D_x^2-D_y^2}{\sin(x-y)};D_x=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x};D_y=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}$

I am used to finding the value of $\dfrac{1}{F(D)}\sin ax$ where $D^2$ is replaced by $-a^2$ if $F(-a^2)\neq 0$ otherwise used the form for $e^{ix}$

But how should I use this fact when there are two partial derivatives available?

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of the notation?

Comment: @Jonas;edited the question

Comment: I guess that we don't know what $\dfrac{1}{D_x^2-D_y^2}$ means.

Comment: OP is trying to solve $(D_x^2 -D_y^2)f=\sin(x-y)$. It's just an irritating functional notation. So $f_{xx}(x,y)-f_{yy}(x,y)=\sin(x-y)$ is another common notation. @Jonas

Comment: The title is terribly misleading, however - you are not trying to find any partial derivative. @Amartya

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Thank you very much!